# How to create hierarchy data in JavaScript by providing dynamic groups and summing the value?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to create a dynamic hierarchy based on my groups and rollup sum to top level, also if I am providing a large amount of data browser is getting hang.

I have the below data:

```
 var data = [
   {
      "country":"Spain",
      "orderNumber":10394,
      "year":2018,
      "countrycode":"es",
      "quantityOrdered":30,
      "priceEach":60.28,
      "productName":"1950's Chicago Surface Lines Streetcar",
      "productLine":"Trains",
      "sortkey":3,
      "productCode":"S32_3207",
      "month":"March",
      "extendedPrice":1808.4,
      "orderDate":"2018-03-15 00:00:00"
   },
   {
      "country":"France",
      "orderNumber":10395,
      "year":2018,
      "countrycode":"fr",
      "quantityOrdered":32,
      "priceEach":105.33,
      "productName":"1972 Alfa Romeo GTA",
      "productLine":"Classic Cars",
      "sortkey":3,
      "productCode":"S10_4757",
      "month":"March",
      "extendedPrice":3370.56,
      "orderDate":"2018-03-17 00:00:00"
   },
   {
      "country":"France",
      "orderNumber":10395,
      "year":2018,
      "countrycode":"fr",
      "quantityOrdered":33,
      "priceEach":69.12,
      "productName":"2001 Ferrari Enzo",
      "productLine":"Classic Cars",
      "sortkey":3,
      "productCode":"S12_1108",
      "month":"March",
      "extendedPrice":2280.96,
      "orderDate":"2018-03-17 00:00:00"
   },
   {
      "country":"France",
      "orderNumber":10395,
      "year":2018,
      "countrycode":"fr",
      "quantityOrdered":46,
      "priceEach":123.76,
      "productName":"Diamond T620 Semi-Skirted Tanker",
      "productLine":"Trucks and Buses",
      "sortkey":3,
      "productCode":"S50_1392",
      "month":"March",
      "extendedPrice":5692.96,
      "orderDate":"2018-03-17 00:00:00"
   },
   {
      "country":"France",
      "orderNumber":10395,
      "year":2018,
      "countrycode":"fr",
      "quantityOrdered":45,
      "priceEach":199.49,
      "productName":"1962 City of Detroit Streetcar",
      "productLine":"Trains",
      "sortkey":3,
      "productCode":"S50_1514",
      "month":"March",
      "extendedPrice":8977.05,
      "orderDate":"2018-03-17 00:00:00"
   },
   {
      "country":"USA",
      "orderNumber":10396,
      "year":2018,
      "countrycode":"us",
      "quantityOrdered":33,
      "priceEach":185.13,
      "productName":"1969 Ford Falcon",
      "productLine":"Classic Cars",
      "sortkey":3,
      "productCode":"S12_3891",
      "month":"March",
      "extendedPrice":6109.29,
      "orderDate":"2018-03-23 00:00:00"
   },
   {
      "country":"USA",
      "orderNumber":10396,
      "year":2018,
      "countrycode":"us",
      "quantityOrdered":33,
      "priceEach":159.81,
      "productName":"1903 Ford Model A",
      "productLine":"Vintage Cars",
      "sortkey":3,
      "productCode":"S18_3140",
      "month":"March",
      "extendedPrice":5273.73,
      "orderDate":"2018-03-23 00:00:00"
   },
   {
      "country":"USA",
      "orderNumber":10396,
      "year":2018,
      "countrycode":"us",
      "quantityOrdered":24,
      "priceEach":89.75,
      "productName":"Collectable Wooden Train",
      "productLine":"Trains",
      "sortkey":3,
      "productCode":"S18_3259",
      "month":"March",
      "extendedPrice":2154,
      "orderDate":"2018-03-23 00:00:00"
   },
   {
      "country":"USA",
      "orderNumber":10396,
      "year":2018,
      "countrycode":"us",
      "quantityOrdered":45,
      "priceEach":105.32,
      "productName":"1904 Buick Runabout",
      "productLine":"Vintage Cars",
      "sortkey":3,
      "productCode":"S18_4522",
      "month":"March",
      "extendedPrice":4739.4,
      "orderDate":"2018-03-23 00:00:00"
   },
   {
      "country":"USA",
      "orderNumber":10396,
      "year":2018,
      "countrycode":"us",
      "quantityOrdered":49,
      "priceEach":116.75,
      "productName":"18th century schooner",
      "productLine":"Ships",
      "sortkey":3,
      "productCode":"S24_2011",
      "month":"March",
      "extendedPrice":5720.75,
      "orderDate":"2018-03-23 00:00:00"
   },
   {
      "country":"USA",
      "orderNumber":10396,
      "year":2018,
      "countrycode":"us",
      "quantityOrdered":27,
      "priceEach":83.2,
      "productName":"1912 Ford Model T Delivery Wagon",
      "productLine":"Vintage Cars",
      "sortkey":3,
      "productCode":"S24_3151",
      "month":"March",
      "extendedPrice":2246.4,
      "orderDate":"2018-03-23 00:00:00"
   },
   {
      "country":"USA",
      "orderNumber":10396,
      "year":2018,
      "countrycode":"us",
      "quantityOrdered":37,
      "priceEach":90.57,
      "productName":"1940 Ford Delivery Sedan",
      "productLine":"Vintage Cars",
      "sortkey":3,
      "productCode":"S24_3816",
      "month":"March",
      "extendedPrice":3351.09,
      "orderDate":"2018-03-23 00:00:00"
   },
   {
      "country":"USA",
      "orderNumber":10396,
      "year":2018,
      "countrycode":"us",
      "quantityOrdered":39,
      "priceEach":66.67,
      "productName":"The Schooner Bluenose",
      "productLine":"Ships",
      "sortkey":3,
      "productCode":"S700_1138",
      "month":"March",
      "extendedPrice":2600.13,
      "orderDate":"2018-03-23 00:00:00"
   },
   {
      "country":"France",
      "orderNumber":10397,
      "year":2018,
      "countrycode":"fr",
      "quantityOrdered":32,
      "priceEach":80.55,
      "productName":"The Mayflower",
      "productLine":"Ships",
      "sortkey":3,
      "productCode":"S700_1938",
      "month":"March",
      "extendedPrice":2577.6,
      "orderDate":"2018-03-28 00:00:00"
   }
]
```

I have created below function but its not working properly

```
var groups = ['country', 'productLine', 'month']; // this can be dynamic 
var sum = ['priceEach']; // this can be dynamic 

function createGroup (groups, data, sum, childNode) {
    let [primaryGroup, ...rest] = groups;

    let groupedData = data.reduce((acc, current) => {
    let chunk = {
        'Name': current[primaryGroup],
        [primaryGroup]: current[primaryGroup],
        [sum]: data.filter(item => item[primaryGroup] === current[primaryGroup])
        .map(el => el[sum])
        .reduce((total, current) => total + current),
       ...(rest.length > 0 ? {[groups[childNode]]: createGroup(rest, data, sum,childNode+1 )} : {})
    }

    acc.push(chunk)
    return acc
  }, [])
    .reduce((acc, current) => {
        const x = acc.find(item => item[primaryGroup] === current[primaryGroup])
        return !x ? acc.concat([current]) : acc
    }, [])

  return groupedData;
}

const tree = createGroup(groups,data,sum, 1);
```

Required below sample result (I haven't included other country but I need all)

```
[
   {
      "country":[
         {
            "Name":"Spain",
            "priceEach":60.28,
            "productline":[
               {
                  "Name":"Trains",
                  "priceEach":60.28,
                  "month":[
                     {
                        "Name":"March",
                        "priceEach":60.28
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "country":[
         {
            "Name":"France",
            "priceEach":578.25,
            "productline":[
               {
                  "Name":"Classic Cars",
                  "priceEach":174.45,
                  "month":[
                     {
                        "Name":"March",
                        "priceEach":174.45
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "Name":"Trucks and Buses",
                  "priceEach":123.76,
                  "month":[
                     {
                        "Name":"March",
                        "priceEach":123.76
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "Name":"Trains",
                  "priceEach":199.49,
                  "month":[
                     {
                        "Name":"April",
                        "priceEach":199.49
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "Name":"Ships",
                  "priceEach":80.55,
                  "month":[
                     {
                        "Name":"June",
                        "priceEach":80.55
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: If the browser is hanging, my guess is that you made an infinite loop, which is possible since you're calling your function recursively. This should be easy enough to find and fix.

Comment: You're probably being downvoted because your question is too specific and can be solved by debugging your function. Your approach is fine.

Comment: Hi @Halcyon, Could you please help me here where i am wrong ?

Comment: Sorry no. Your function looks horrible. I don't want to debug that. You can't even bother to fix the indentation.

Comment: The classic way: https://jsfiddle.net/hs28bLma/

Comment: Hi @Valijon, Thanks for your answer could you please put this in the answer also if possible could you please make it dynamic so that it works as per the groups provided by the user currently its static so that I can mark as answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is probably `hangs` because of `O(n log n)` (you iterate the same `data` over and over).

**Note**: `priceEach` is static in this solution, but you can redesign the recursive function

```
function createGroup(groups, i, data, parent){
        
    //Take current group    
    var group  = groups[i];
    var nGroup = groups[i+1];
    
    // No more group, stop recursivity
    if (!group) return parent;
    
    // Now, let's reduce by current group
    //FIX: We need to add an empty item to force the reduce method
    if(data.length == 1) {
        data.push({priceEach:0});
    }
    
    var root = data.reduce((prev, next) => {        
        //First time, add prev value
        if(parent.length == 0) {
        
            var item = {};
            item[group] = {
                "Name": prev[group],
                "priceEach": prev.priceEach
            }
            //Next group?
            if(nGroup){
                item[group][nGroup] = createGroup(groups, i+1, [prev], []);
            }
        
            parent.push(item);
        }
    
        //Check if we need to reduce
        for(var item of parent){
            if(item[group].Name == next[group]) {
                item[group].priceEach += next.priceEach;
                //Next group?
                if(nGroup){
                    item[group][nGroup] = createGroup(groups, i+1, [prev, next], item[group][nGroup]);
                }
                return parent;
            }
        }
        
        //We did not reduce, so add next as item
        if(next[group]) {
            var item = {};
            item[group] = {
                "Name": next[group],
                "priceEach": next.priceEach
            }
            //Next group?
            if(nGroup){
                item[group][nGroup] = createGroup(groups, i+1, [next], []);
            }
        
            parent.push(item);
        }

        return parent;
    });
    
    return root;
}

createGroup(["country", "productLine", "month"], 0, data, []);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgufebyn/)

If `country, productLine, month` are static, you can run the [classic way](https://jsfiddle.net/hs28bLma/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer its really helped me